# Saving Cache from api response on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I Would like to seek advice for a simple way to cache this response from my API on flutter. What I am intending to do is when there no internet available it will use the cache item and if there is internet available it will update the cache to the latest one.The code below is the current API call that I am using.

```
 _getCurrentPlanDetails() async{
      var url = "http://dmp-portal-fixture.herokuapp.com/getCurrentPlan";
      var response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200){
        var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
          setState(() {
            currentPlan = jsonResponse["data"]["CurrentPlan"];
            cutOffDate = jsonResponse["data"]["CutoffDate"];
            contractExpiry = jsonResponse["data"]["ContractExpiry"];
            monthsRemaining =jsonResponse["data"]["MonthsRemaining"];
          });
          print("get Current plan");
      }else{
      print("error current plan");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use Sqlite database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple packages that handle this depending on the use-case of your requirements:

1. [localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage) which is a JSON based storage.
2. [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for storing key-value pairs.
3. [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) for storing all your access token and security related components of the app such as all session information, user credentials etc...
4. [SQL database](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) there is a quite extensive tutorial on storing files in a databese in Flutter, so I suggest reading that one as well in case you need to preserve a lot of app related data in case no internet is available.

Comment: I shared_preferences also called cache. just to clarify.

Btw I have an experience on using shared preferences

Comment: It is a way of storing data persistently until your app gets deleted. It gets stored within the app bundle, so once app gets removed, all the files from shared preferences are also removed with it.